# How do I perfectly center a Tkinter window on the x axis?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple clock I made for the sole purpose to be a decoration on my desktop, but I just cannot center it right. It's always a little too much to the left or right.

I tried changing my x value, and even changed how I calculated how to position the window in order to get it perfectly center.
Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import strftime

class ClockApp:
    #creating window and positioning
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.overrideredirect(True)
        self.root.configure(bg="black")
        self.root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', 'black')
        self.root.wm_attributes('-topmost', False)
        self.root.update_idletasks()

        self.width = 500
        self.height = 500
        screenWidth = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        screenHeight = self.root.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (screenWidth - self.width) / 2
        print(x)
        y = (screenHeight - self.height) / 3.5

        self.root.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (self.width, self.height, x, y))
        self.root.resizable(False, False)

        self.create_widgets()
        self.update()
        self.root.mainloop()

    #creating gui elements
    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hrmin_label = Label(self.root, font=("Consolas", 100), fg="white", bg="black")
        self.hrmin_label.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)

        self.sec_label = Label(self.root, font=("Consolas", 50), fg="white", bg="black")
        self.sec_label.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.ampm_label = Label(self.root, font=("Consolas", 50), fg="white", bg="black")
        self.ampm_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.day_label = Label(self.root, font=("Consolas", 35), fg="white", bg="black")
        self.day_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

    #updating gui elements to tell time
    def update(self):
        hrmin_string = strftime("%I:%M")
        self.hrmin_label.config(text=hrmin_string)

        sec_string = strftime("%S")
        self.sec_label.config(text=sec_string)

        ampm_string = strftime("%p")
        self.ampm_label.config(text=ampm_string)

        day_string = strftime("%A, %B %d")
        self.day_label.config(text=day_string)

        self.root.after(1000, self.update)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ClockApp()
```

Comment: Try putting the clock part in a frame and use `.pack()` on both the frame and the `day_label`.

Comment: I'm trying to align the clock to my desktop icons, but it seems that either tkinter struggles with doing that, or windows desktop icons aren't centered properly, because they just won't align. This solution didn't seem to work to properly align the clock (probably should have led with this from the start).